# how to replace 3rd row in a file using sed?

Tags: command-line, sed, text-processing

I need to change a variable in a file using a bash script, i think sed is the way to go but i can't figure out the regular expression.

I have tried replacing a character in the file but then understood that what i'm replacing will be changing too.

Can you help with replacing the 3rd and 4th row in a file using sed ?

an e.g. of what i'm referring to

```
mode blender 
type kitchen 
blender.net 5.5.5.5.6:33 blender blender 
blender.com 5.5.5.5.5:33 blender blender
```

i want to be able to change the whole 3rd and 4th row with

```
blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blender
```

Comment: Please post an example input and your desired output from that..

Comment: mode blender
type kitchen
blender.net 5.5.5.5.6:33 blender blender
blender.com 5.5.5.5.5:33 blender blender

i want to be able to change the whole 3rd and 4th row with 
blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blnder

Comment: Please add this to your question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indicate a range of lines to operate on in `sed` e.g. in your case `3,4` indicating line 3 to(and) 4:

```
sed -r '3,4 s/.*/blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blender/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
mode blender 
type kitchen
blender.net 5.5.5.5.6:33 blender blender
blender.com 5.5.5.5.5:33 blender blender

$ sed -r '3,4 s/.*/blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blender/' file.txt
mode blender 
type kitchen
blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blender
blender.net x.x.x.x:33 blender blender
```

Here we are doing the desired substitution operation on line 3 and 4.

---

From a variable:

```
$ var=5.5.5.5.6:3

$ sed -r "3,4 s/.*/blender.net $var blender blender/" file.txt
mode blender 
type kitchen
blender.net 5.5.5.5.6:3 blender blender
blender.net 5.5.5.5.6:3 blender blender
```

Comment: what if this value is a variable : 5.5.5.5.6:3 ?

i need to pass this sed action in a script for a variable.

Comment: @VitalikJimbei Check my edits..

Comment: great, thx !! i'll be able to check it later in action !!

Comment: i have an issue.

the command is not actually replacing anything in the file per se. 

when i execute it it shows me the result i need, when i enter the file th changes are not altered.

Comment: @VitalikJimbei You need the `-i` option to edit the file in place..to edit the file in place also keep a backup as `.bak`: `sed -ri.bak "3,4 s/....../" file.txt`

Comment: big thx to you my friend. the backup thing is just what i need !!!

Comment: @VitalikJimbei Glad i could help :)